# Reliance 3G application not running in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 3g

I installed Reliance 3G usb modem successfully and found Reliance 3G icon in dash. But its not starting when click on it. When i tried to run from terminal I got the below error.

```
./Reliance_3G: error while loading shared libraries: libqt-mt.so.3: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`
```

What can I do to start it up with no issue?

Answer (score 0):

Those binaries have been compiled in 32-bit system.All you need is 32-bit libraries in your 64-bit system. 
Open terminal & type :
`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`